# Connecting Phone to PC...USB socket seems to be dirty

Tags: usb

It used to work.

I could connect my phone to my PC with a USB cable and then browse the phone, like a mounted USB drive, with Windows explorer.   Moving files back and forth was easy.

Then it stopped working.  I used a wooden toothpick to dig some lint and dirt out of the phone's USB port.  I also hit it with compressed air.

It helped but it is really intermittent...I have to wiggle and jiggle the USB cable to get the drive to mount.  And it's not reliable.   I tried another cable with the same result.

**So...what is the best way to clean a phone's USB port?**

Comment: Are you sure the port is still dirty? The mechanical force you used for (un)plugging and cleaning may have caused a loose connection between the USB socket and the phone mainboard.

Comment: the only solution is resoldering and replace new usb jack for ~ 30 bucks. or if you're lucky you can replace usb connector board DIY (much cheaper). watch on youtube, buy on aliexpress

Answer (score 0):

First, I powered off the phone.

Then, I took some **contact cleaner** (the kind used to clean old TV tuners and potentiometers) and sprayed it into the female USB port.  I plugged and unplugged the male USB plug several times.  I blew out the port with compressed air and powered the phone back on.

Success!

(thanks for the suggestions and comments)